# Общение компьютеров p2p на python

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, p2p, blockchain

**У меня задача, чтобы 3-6 компьютеров общались между собой p2p (блокчейн) и потом отдавали данные в другой узел.**

Нашел хороший модуль с документацией: [p2p-python](https://github.com/namuyan/p2p-python)
.

Вот пример работы прямой передачи используя сокеты: [Direct command](https://github.com/namuyan/p2p-python/blob/master/doc/DIRECT_CMD.md).

Вот пример работы с channel threads: [Channel tool](https://github.com/namuyan/p2p-python/blob/master/doc/CHANNEL.md).

***Я так понимаю мне надо выбрать решение channel для этой задачи и изучать его?***

Comment: Какое отношение имеет блокчейн к p2p?

Comment: какая у вас конкретная задача? в чём вопрос? Или это попытка рекламы левых проектов?

Comment: p2p в блокчейн для общения компьютеров между собой для обмена информации (достижения консенсуса).